# Trouble with If Statement Inside For Loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

So I'm trying to use this code to print a statement if it reaches the end of the loop without break being called in the statement before it which would mean that the program got a match and then needs to print it. However, my if (k+1...) statement never gets branched into always skipped over. Why would this be?

```
else {
            cout << "test" << endl;
            looklen = look.length();
            for (j = 0;j < numdist;j++) {
                for (k = 0;k < looklen;k++) {
                    //cout << "test2" << endl;
                    if (look[k] = '?') {
                        k++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (look[k] != distinct[j][k]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (k + 1 == looklen) {
                        cout << "test3" << endl;
                        cout << look << " : matches " << distinct[j] << " " << distinctnum[j]+1 << " time(s)." << endl;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `if (look[k] = '?')` is an assignment, not a comparison.  You need to use `==` to compare.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (look[k] = '?')
```

Is always true (because it is an assignment), which means the continue is always executed. You probably meant

```
if (look[k] == '?')
```

Which is a comparison

Answer (score 0):

`=` operator is for assigning value

`==` operator is conditional

so it must be like this :

```
if (look[k] == '?')
```